# How to buy a song within a family group without charging a family organizer?

Tags: itunes, apple-id, family-sharing

Our adult daughter put us on "family share."  If I try to buy a song from "iTunes Store," it sends a verification code to her phone, and if she passes it on to me and I enter it, it charges her payment method.

I think I can get around that by reversing my acceptance of Family Sharing, but **is there another way?**

Comment: (I'll probably turn it off anyway, because Family Sharing has other unwanted side-effects: it prevents playing tracks when off-line and puts our children and grandchildren on our "find my" list.

Comment: have her set up second account dedicated to you with your payment method

Comment: Thanks, but I'd rather go back to just the account I've used since she was in middle school.  :-)

Comment: If she is the adult - is she controlling your spending...

Comment: You can opt out of family find my once it turns on at joining. You also can fund all your purchases easily.

Answer (score 1):

The family organizer should allow you to purchase without a code as an “adult” and you all can settle up periodically.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208687

Adding funds doesn’t require a physical gift card, but if you prefer , you can also purchase gift cards often at 80% or more discount and  load up your individual Apple Account balance with your payment method before you purchase.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211187

That balance is carried by your account (and all other accounts in the family can carry distinct gift balances) and purchases drain the balance before the organizer’s default payment method is used for any shortfall.

We did just this for 8 plus years and very few purchases ever leaked through.

Comment: Our Apple account balance is not available as a payment method.  It always was before we accepted the family share.  Of course, "settle up periodically" is an option if we could actually make a purchase.  Apple no longer allows us to decline two-factor authentication, and the code gets sent to my son-in-law's phone.

Comment: Not a big deal anyway, because we have never used any of the benefits, and probably never will.  And as mentioned in a comment, it has at least three features that are very unwanted.

Comment: @WGroleau The way bmike describes how it should work is correct (i.e. purchases drain the balance before the organiser’s default payment method is used for any shortfall). However, I've seen your situation arise before and actually helped someone in this situation a few weeks back. The fix involved everyone checking their payment methods are current, including default method, and then ensuring they had a balance on their individuals Apple IDs because if there's no balance it always goes to the family organiser's payment method. Not how it should work in my opinion, just the way it is.

Comment: I know how to add funds, so I'll remember that.  Although, I'd really like to revert our acceptance of sharing.  The other day, a song I had purchased was missing from my library, and when I clicked the download, it said I had to enable iCloud sync for that.  When I did so, it MOVED most, if not all of my songs to iCloud when my internal SSD has two gigabytes free. When I got them back, the metadata from one of them had overwritten that on several hundred others, and a fesw hundred are gone!  And those aren't purchased songs; I created them a few at a time over more than a year.

Comment: I tried to make another purchase.  This time, instead of defaulting to our daughter, it asked me to login and choose a payment method.  "Apple pay"—which we have used in the past—was not an option.  It did not accept a valid Visa which has been used in the past.  Tried the "add funds" method cited above.  Same result.